# UI testing framework that doesnt depend on xpaths?

Tags: testing, user-interface, selenium, automated-tests

Are there any UI testing frameworks that DONT depend on the xpaths/element IDs/element Classes. The web application I work on changes ids and classes all the time because of lot of different A/B tests we run. What are my options here? May be something that is dependent on javascript events rather than sniffing for particular id or classname? (just a thought)

Answer (score 0):

1) Have a talk to developers. I just faced the same problem, realising, that developers can make unique IDs on a page even there are lets say nightly builds. It costs little time extra from developer point of view, but from quality assurance... every project manager should cover your back.

2) XPath can use "contains" so you do not search for string perfect values

Answer (score 0):

If there are always changes in your AUT, then you should first ask the question - should the tests be automated.

If the changes in the application is only for the ID's and not for the UI elements and functionality then the question would be for the developers on why are you changing the elementID now rather than doing it correct initially.

If your AB testing is not too frequent, and is something which gets turned OFF and ON frequently one way of tackling would be to have different tests. Yes, that is going to be tough from maintenance perspective. But you too can take a leaf out AB testing. Put flags in your tests to denote what should be tested?

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested the correct way is to have the id's not changed. But I recommend you to try [SIKULI](http://sikuli.org/). It uses screenshots...